# Can we ignore indeterminate terms when we integrate?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am doing some simple integration by parts for a statistics problem and have managed to obtain the indefinite form of the integral. However, when I plug in my parameter values I get an indefinite term. Can I ignore this term and obtain my answer from the remaining terms? Here is my work so far:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^{x(1+y)}}dx = -\frac{e^{-x(1+y)}{xy+x+y}}{{y+1}^2}$$

(obtained via the tabular method and verified by Wolfram Alpha)

With parameter values $0$ and $\infty$ I obtained:

$$\frac{-e^{-\infty}\cdot{\infty}}{{y+1}^2} - \frac{-{e^0}\cdot1}{{y+1}^2}$$

The term on the left is indeterminate $(0\cdot\infty)$ but according to Wolfram the integral is the term on the right by itself. So, do we just throw out indeterminate terms in integration?

Comment: Close to $0$ divided by huge is close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula seems to be wrong : the antiderivative seems to be Exp[-x(1+y)] (1+x+x y)/(1+y)^2. I suppose that you missed a couple of parenthesis. Then, there is not problem except if y = -1 in which case the antiderivative is just x^2/2. If y is not equal to -1, then the result is 1/(1+y)^2. WIth regard to what you wrote, remember that x Exp[-x] goes to zero when x goes to infinity.